# Toggle heroku maintenance mode without CLI or Web UI

Tags: heroku, jenkins, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using Jenkins to run tests before deploying to Heroku using a git publisher plugin. I want to sandwich my deploy with maintenance mode ON/OFF but don't want to install the heroku toolbelt ([reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)) on my jenkins machine (nor do I want to go to the Web UI and toggle the maintenance mode manually). I don't want to install the heroku toolbelt on jenkins because it adds to the customization and configuration I'd need to do to the jenkins installation and I want to keep my jenkins instance as disposable as possible...driven rather by source code pipelines (Jenkinsfile).

Ideas:

- utilize a docker image that has the heroku toolbelt installed on it
- utilize a multi-buildpack that does it for me?

Any suggestions or experience on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use heroku's platform api to do this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app-update

The following curl request will put your app into maintenance mode:

```
curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME \
  -d '{"maintenance": true}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <heroku token>
```

You will just need to replace the app name, as well as the token.
You can generate OAuth tokens using the [cli-oauth](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-oauth) cli plugin locally.

Comment: thanks for the interesting suggestion +1. However wouldn't that mean installing cli-oauth on my jenkins box instead of the heroku toolbelt...Six of one, half a dozen of the other?

Comment: No. You need to retrieve a token only once, locally. You then just need to set that token into your jenkins config.